# Plotting IP-based or chat-based locations on a map, in real-time (Zoom conference)

Tags: api, maps, video-conferencing, zoom

I will be organising a Zoom event with around 300 participants distributed across several continents. As an ice-breaker, I'd like to start by asking everyone to type in the chat where they are joining from (city, country).

I recall having been at a conference where the organisers were showing a live map where pins were being placed automatically, in real time, with each incoming geographically-valid entry that came into the chat. But I've no idea how they achieved that, and googling for something like this (e.g. a Zoom API or something) did not reveal anything obvious.

Equally fine would be to have this done based on the participants' IP addresses, instead of self-reported location in the chat. But in a Zoom setting, this might be even more difficult.

One of the organisers will be able to dedicate his attention to this, while people are typing in their cities. However, a manual solution (such as copying & pasting each entry into a multi-location plotter like [www.easymapmaker.com](http://www.easymapmaker.com)) will not work, if this ice-breaker is to elicit a few hundred replies within one minute or so.

Any recommendations for how this can be achieved (without a massive programmatic effort) would be appreciated!

Comment: *"without a massive programmatic effort"* - you'll be lucky. User types London… where are they? UK, Canada… or one of the other 27 Londons in the world? [I've just come back from Miami Beach, via Boston… & didn't need to leave the UK.] You can programatically ask the user for their location, provided back by the computer/devices own Location Services [but that's way above my paygrade & would be a question for StackExchange]. Websites ask me that all the time, I usually say no.

Comment: you have a point :) thanks for your input!